# ABAddressBookRef in singleton

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

I have several calls to ABAddressBookCreate() in the app I'm working on. For iOS >=6 compatibility I thought to use a singleton to check for access to the address book and to return a ABAddressBookRef from the singleton. However I'm not sure how correctly release the ABAddressBookRef instance or whether the this approach is safe to use.

```
+(ABAddressBookRef)loadContacts {

    ABAddressBookRef ref;

    if ([self isABAddressBookCreateWithOptionsAvailable]) {
        CFErrorRef error = nil;

        ref = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL,&error);
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(ref, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (error) {

                    [self showErrorDialog:@"Error"];

                } else if (!granted) {
                    [self showErrorDialog:@"Not granted"];
                }

            });
        });

     //   [(id)ref autorelease]; not working..
        return ref;

    } else {
        // iOS 4/5
        ref = ABAddressBookCreate();
    //    [(id)ref autorelease];

    return ref;

    }
}
```

Call in ViewController:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = [AddressBookAccess loadContacts];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this method already exists in the ABAddressBook class:

- (ABAddressBook *)sharedAddressBook

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/ABAddressBook/sharedAddressBook) for more info.

Comment: That is for OSX, the original poster was asking about iOS